# Dictate home ribbon idMso

Tags: vba, powerpoint, add-in, ribbon

I am coding a custom add-in for PowerPoint and customizing the ribbon. I would like to hide the "Voice" group (big dictate button) from the Home tab, but I can't find the idMso for the element.

Anyone has experience in that?

Comment: Very important for this question: Which ***version*** of PowerPoint is in question? And are you certain this group is part of PowerPoint and not a third-party add-in?

Comment: Cindy's onto it. By default, PowerPoint doesn't have a Home>Voice group. Just deactivate the add-in that's creating it and your job is done. Please post again if you need help deactivating it.

Comment: Yeah I am quite confident that it's on by default (no add-ins are active).

The group is Voice > Dictation Menu in Home Tab